# MySql insert trigger after inserting data into another table

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

i have created a table trans in which i want to store data after a insert into table resultate. When I run my trigger, I get back two much data in trans, it seems that for every each row the trigger store the complete statement into the db. How I have to change my trigger that just at the end of the insert statement into resultate, the trigger store the statment once into table trans?

Here is my trigger...

```
   CREATE TRIGGER trans_trigger
   AFTER INSERT
   ON resultate FOR EACH ROW
   insert into trans(ID_trans, Spieltag, Heimteam, ID) 
SELECT     
     CASE
        WHEN @Heimteam = Heimteam THEN @ID_before
        ELSE NULL
    END AS ID_Final,
    Spieltag,
    @Heimteam:=Heimteam as Heimteam,
    @ID_before:=IDer as ID
FROM
    resultate
ORDER BY Heimteam, Spieltag;
```

Comment: The trigger is going to insert a row into `trans` for every row in `resultate`. That's because it's running a `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM resultate` with no `WHERE` clause.  To reference just the row that was just inserted, remove the query `FROM resultate` and use `NEW.heimteam`, `NEW.spieltag`, etc. to reference values of the row that was just inserted.

Comment: But I need this query because there is logic inside.

Comment: What we're not seeing is a *specification*, an explanation/definition of what the trigger should do, helpfully illustrated with example data and sample results. Is there a way to get the trigger to not insert a row for every row in `resultate`? Yes there is... avoid doing an `INSERT ,,, SELECT ...` that gets every row in `resultate`. Maybe limit the number of rows returned by the SELECT. Maybe wrap that query in the trigger inside a another SELECT (use the existing query as an inline view), and maybe add a WHERE clause on the outer query, with NEW.col references that limits the rows returned.

Comment: Thanks I have the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my query. Now just the insert row will be stored in the trans db.

```
   Select a11.ID_Final, a11.Spieltag, a11.Heimteam,a11.ID from
(
SELECT     
     CASE
        WHEN @Heimteam = Heimteam THEN @ID_before
        ELSE NULL
    END AS ID_Final,
    Spieltag,
    @Heimteam:=Heimteam as Heimteam,
    @ID_before:=ID as ID
FROM
    resultate
ORDER BY Heimteam, Spieltag 
) as a11
  join
 (
Select ID from resultate 
)as a12 
on a11.ID = a12.ID where a12.ID = new.ID;
```